Password-protect an excel file on DataBricks environment
I have a requirement to password protect an excel file, meaning no one should be able to read from it unless they have the password). I want to use DataBricks because that's where the file is getting generated. I have explored some options online, but either they don't meet the functionality (openpyxl, pandas), or need a windows machine (pywin32)- since DataBricks uses Linux machine, I can't use this lib. Can someone please recommend the way forward?

Aren't excels just archives? Maybe you can treat it as a zip and add a password as you would a zip?

@Daviid, that is valid as long as it's understood that unlike an Excel password protected file which Excel will open and ask for a password to complete, adding a password to the zipping process means Excel won't recognise it. The file would need to be unzipped (using password) and re-zipped again without a password for Excel use. Or just zip the file with a password, as a file and again unzip before use, so it's make up is not relevant.

You can use the following code snippet, which operates within the files you intend to encrypt and does not require accessing any other directories.

Azure Databricks allows you to enhance data security and access control by integrating with Azure Key Vault to use customer-managed keys.
"The below code taken from PGP Encryption / Decryption in Databricks by @Kaniz helps you to Encrypting a file using public key:"
import pgpy
from pgpy.constants import PubKeyAlgorithm, KeyFlags, HashAlgorithm, SymmetricKeyAlgorithm, CompressionAlgorithm
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import base64 
import io
 
KEY_PUB = base64.b64decode(publicb64).decode("ascii").lstrip()  
#print(KEY_PUB)
 
pub_key = pgpy.PGPKey()
pub_key.parse(KEY_PUB)
pass
#-READ THE FILE FROM MOUNT POINT-----------------
with io.open('/dbfs/mnt/sample_data/california_housing_test.csv', "r",newline='') as csv_file:
    input_data = csv_file.read()                   # The io and newline retains the CRLF
    
t0 = timer()
#PGP Encryption start
msg = pgpy.PGPMessage.new(input_data)
###### this returns a new PGPMessage that contains an encrypted form of the original message
encrypted_message = pub_key.encrypt(msg)
pgpstr = str(encrypted_message)
with open('/dbfs/mnt/sample_data/california_housing_test.csv.pgp', "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(pgpstr)
print("Encryption Complete :" + str(timer()-t0))

Reference:
PGP Encryption / Decryption in Databricks
Data security and encryption
